# Carthage run script Xcode output files

Tags: xcode, xcode9, carthage

I'am doing my first demo with Carthage and looked through lots of tutorials and nowhere I saw usage of **Output files** setting in Xcode in Run script section.
I understand why do we need **Input files**, but can't get why do we need **output files**?

Can someone explain this moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use it to write some custom output to a file, instead of, say, printing it to the console.
Once you add your file in the output section, you may write to it like this:

```
echo "Some custom output" > "$(SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0)"
```

Your CI systems may then read this file and perform some actions, log data, etc.

Comment: So if I not using this I got some default destination?

Comment: The console, and derived data.